# How to have all my paths in list object after running a for loop?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am more a python user than an R script writer.
In my current project I am using R.
I have multiple pathsets, for multiple samples, and I wanted to make my code less dense.

```
dir.path <- "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/"
file.list <- list("13H01640", "13H08091", "14H04547", "15H24261", "16H25543", "17H15169","G71246", "H03J73","H20567", "H21057", "H41-178" , "H46280" , "H48D81", "H50743")
data.path <- "/outs/"
i <- list(seq(1, length(file.list)))
for (elt in i){
  x <- sprintf("pathset_%s", elt)
}

for (file.name in file.list){
  for (j in x){
      j <- list(paste0(dir.path, file.name, data.path))
  }
}
```

The problem with this code portion is that : in my final j object, I only find the last element of the file.list.

Does anyone know how I should do to get all the elements from file.list into the j list ?

Thanks you in advance for your insight and help :)

Comment: You're reassigning `j` each time you go through the loop and not creating any output that would be accessible outside of that loop. But there's also no real reason to use loops like this in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any loops for achieving the results you are looking for in R. Because R is vectorized.
Here's how you can get the results:

```
j <- paste0(dir.path, file.list, data.path)
```

Output:

```
[1] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/13H01640/outs/"
 [2] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/13H08091/outs/"
 [3] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/14H04547/outs/"
 [4] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/15H24261/outs/"
 [5] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/16H25543/outs/"
 [6] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/17H15169/outs/"
 [7] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/G71246/outs/"  
 [8] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/H03J73/outs/"  
 [9] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/H20567/outs/"  
[10] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/H21057/outs/"  
[11] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/H41-178/outs/" 
[12] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/H46280/outs/"  
[13] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/H48D81/outs/"  
[14] "/home/gwenneg/Projet_Spatial/H50743/outs/"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my naïve question !

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider accepting it as an answer by checking the grey tick n the left side of this answer.